# Oracle PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: database, oracle

I wrote this query to simulate variables being passed to server-side query and it keeps giving me this error "ORA-06550: line 11, column 2:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
".
[image: Oracle PLS Error]

Here is my query

```
DECLARE

    P_CONTRACTS VARCHAR(60) := NULL;
    P_START_DATE  DATE:='01/01/2010';
    P_END_DATE  DATE:='05/01/2010';
    P_CONTRACT_TYPE  VARCHAR(30):='Annual';
    P_CONTRACT_STATUS  VARCHAR(30):='OPEN';

BEGIN

 SELECT DISTINCT

       CONTRACT_ID,
       SUPPLIER_NAME,
       CONTRACT_NUMBER,
       CONTRACT_TYPE,
       CONTRACT_STATUS,
       CONTRACT_DATE,
       MONTHLY_COMMITTED_LBS,
       PO,
       ORDER_TYPE,
       PRICING_TYPE,
       PURCHASE_VOLUME,
       RECEIVED_VOLUME,
       INTRANSIT,
       (MONTHLY_COMMITTED_LBS - (RECEIVED_VOLUME + INTRANSIT)) AS "NOT_SCHEDULED"

    FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ARR.ID AS CONTRACT_ID,
                    DWPO.SUPPLIER_NAME AS SUPPLIER_NAME,
                    ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER AS CONTRACT_NUMBER,
                    DECODE(ARR.CONTRACT_DESIGNATION, 1, 'ANNUAL', 2, 'MINI-SPOT') AS CONTRACT_TYPE,
                    DECODE(ARR.STATUS, 1, 'OPEN', 2, 'CLOSED', 3, 'CANCELLED') AS CONTRACT_STATUS,
                    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(ARR.START_DATE,-1))+1), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CONTRACT_DATE,
                    ARRB.QUANTITY AS MONTHLY_COMMITTED_LBS,
                    P.PO_NUMBER AS PO,
                    DWPO.PO_TYPE AS ORDER_TYPE,
                    DWPO.PRICE_CALCULATION_TYPE AS PRICING_TYPE,
                    NVL(DW_REPORTS_PKG.GET_RECEIVED_BY_PO(P.PO_NUMBER, ARR.START_DATE, ARR.END_DATE, DWPO.PRODUCT_ID),0) AS "PURCHASE_VOLUME",
                    NVL(DW_REPORTS_PKG.GET_RECEIVED_WEIGHT_BY_PO(P.PO_NUMBER, ARR.START_DATE, ARR.END_DATE, DWPO.PRODUCT_ID),0) AS "RECEIVED_VOLUME",
                    NVL(DW_REPORTS_PKG.GET_IN_TRANSIT_BY_PO(P.PO_NUMBER, ARR.START_DATE, ARR.END_DATE, DWPO.PRODUCT_ID),0) AS "INTRANSIT"

                FROM
                    APP_ARRANGEMENT ARR
                        INNER JOIN APP_CONTRACT_SUPPLIER CS
                            ON (ARR.ID = CS.ARRANGEMENT_ID)
                        INNER JOIN APP_PO P
                            ON(P.ARRANGEMENT_ID = ARR.ID)
                        INNER JOIN DW_PURCHASE_ORDER DWPO
                            ON (DWPO.PO_NUMBER = P.PO_NUMBER)
                        INNER JOIN APP_ARRANGEMENT_BUCKET ARRB
                            ON (ARR.ID = ARRB.ARRANGEMENT_ID)
                WHERE
                        (
                                  (P_CONTRACTS IS NULL OR
                                  (ARR.ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(TXT, INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) + 1, INSTR(TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL+1) - INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) -1)) AS TOKEN
                                    FROM (SELECT ','|| P_CONTRACTS ||',' AS TXT FROM DUAL)
                                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TXT)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TXT,',',''))-1))))
                        )

                AND
                                (P_CONTRACT_TYPE IS NULL OR DECODE(ARR.CONTRACT_DESIGNATION, 1, 'ANNUAL', 2, 'MINISPOT') IN
                                (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(TXT, INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) + 1, INSTR(TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL+1) - INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) -1)) AS TOKEN
                                 FROM (SELECT ','|| P_CONTRACT_TYPE ||',' AS TXT FROM DUAL)
                                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TXT)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TXT,',',''))-1)))

                 AND
                                (P_CONTRACT_STATUS IS NULL OR ARR.STATUS IN
                                (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(TXT, INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) + 1, INSTR(TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL+1) - INSTR (TXT, ',', 1, LEVEL) -1)) AS TOKEN
                                FROM (SELECT ','|| P_CONTRACT_STATUS ||',' AS TXT FROM DUAL)
                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(TXT)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TXT,',',''))-1)))
                AND
                                ((P_START_DATE IS NULL AND P_END_DATE IS NULL) OR TO_DATE(ARRB.MONTH || '/' || ARRB.YEAR, 'MM/YYYY') BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE)

        );
END;
```

I can supply sample DB structure and date that match the query.

Just in case someone thinks it has to do with the Sub-query is doesn't I can run the sub-query no problem hard coding values for dates.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: in PL/SQL you can't run a SELECT without storing the result somewhere. And to store the result you need an `INTO` clause. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS551

Comment: A "query" is an SQL statement. Anything that begins with BEGIN is a PL/SQL block (in your case an "anonymous" block). A block is not a query. You didn't write a query; you wrote a PL/SQL anonymous block. If you want to understand the issue, don't read documentation or Google for things to do with SQL queries - search for "PL/SQL anonymous block" and similar.

Answer (score 0):

declare your query as a cursor and keep coding your pl/sql program ;)

declare
cursor c is
 SELECT DISTINCT .... ;
begin
-- your PL/SQL statement
end;

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on your answer?